# .NET Process unpredicably hangs. Need opinions on alternate solutions

Tags: c#, .net, git, process

I am trying to reach one simple requirement. I would like to create a C# library that talks to the git executable. I am writing a version control tool for my team that will allow access to git commands for non tech-savvy individuals. Unfortunately, I can not use any third party DLL's (I am using Unity and I do not want to push the requirement for Unity pro due to plugins), otherwise I would use GitSharp or something along those lines.

Currently, I have a function called RunGitCommand that is meant to do all my bidding. This snippet is as follows:

```
private void RunGitCommand(string executablePath, string arguments, int maxCommandDurationMilliseconds)
{
    using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
        try
        {
            CommandOutput = string.Empty;
            CommandError = string.Empty;

            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processStartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
            processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            int processedTime = 0;
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                StringBuilder outputData = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder errorData = new StringBuilder();

                process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
                    outputWaitHandle.Set();
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        //outputWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outputData.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    errorWaitHandle.Set();
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        //errorWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorData.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                process.Start();

                if(process.Id == 0)
                {
                    Environment.LogError("Process id is 0. Aborting.");
                    return;
                }

                RunningProcessDescriptor processDescriptor = new RunningProcessDescriptor(maxCommandDurationMilliseconds, process.Id);
                ProcessIds.Add(processDescriptor);

                Thread.Sleep(200);
                int newMaxTime = maxCommandDurationMilliseconds - 100;

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                if (process.WaitForExit(newMaxTime) && outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(newMaxTime) && errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(newMaxTime))
                {
                    process.CancelOutputRead();
                    process.CancelErrorRead();
                    CommandOutput = outputData.ToString();
                    CommandError = errorData.ToString();
                    string combinedOutput = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, new string[]{ CommandError, CommandOutput }).Trim();
                    BatchOutput = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, new string[]{ BatchOutput, string.Format("----------// {0} {1} //----------", executablePath, arguments), CommandOutput }).Trim();
                    BatchError = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, new string[]{ BatchError, string.Format("----------// {0} {1} //----------", executablePath, arguments), CommandError }).Trim();
                    InterpretErrorsAndAddToLists(combinedOutput);
                }
                else
                {
                    process.Close();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }

                ProcessIds.Remove(processDescriptor);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception genericException)
        {
            Environment.LogError(genericException.Message);
            Environment.LogError(genericException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing to note is that I'm using this to run these commands so that they don't execute on the main thread:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
```

As you should be able to identify by my commenting and layout, this function is the result of hours of troubleshooting and I am willing to try anything at this point to make it work. I've already moved to using asynchronous calls for receiving the output/error streams, and even added AutoResetEvent objects to cause my threads to wait for each other (although I am not completely familiar with them and might be doing something wrong).

No matter what I try, it seems to randomly hang and not allow the process to exit. When I manually kill the git process, the output is spit out (and is usually right) and the process exits and everything works as normal.

I'm at the point in troubleshooting and frustration where I need professional input. Here are my questions:

1. Is there something blatantly or obviously wrong with my code below? If I'm doing it wrong, please advise me how to properly execute this code.
2. Is there another solution where I do not need to include third party DLL files and can just use raw .NET to grab the git console process and interact with it (on mac and pc)?
3. Other alternatives to these approaches, such as one i've been considering, that uses a "client/server" architecture. I can use third party dll's and whatnot in a separate downloadable program that communicates to the git plugin via TCP to send and receive output/input to the git process. This one is much more work, but would potentially take less time than troubleshooting the git only version.

Just let me know what your professional opinions are so that I can rest at night :).

I look forward to talking with everyone!

-Zack

Comment: Oh, another thing I forgot to mention. I'm also considering the path of not redirecting stdOut/Err to the Process, but instead adding the pipe to stdOut/Err command onto my arguments and then waiting for that file to be created. The thing I really don't like about that approach is using an IO heavy method for executing commands.

Comment: What's the `Sleep` command achieving? Generally, when I see a `Sleep` used in that way, the problem with the code is not far away!

Comment: That is most likely a remnant of the massive troubleshooting i've had to go through. I think I remember how that came about... I had everything working for me on my dev machine, and all of the sudden the code would hang up while attempting to access the standard output of the Process object. I attempted to stall the thread before reading the output to see if that was the issue and I guess it stayed in there. Ideally, i don't want that wait because I want this tool to be snappy.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a very simple piece of code for executing a non-interactive command, and getting the standard output from the result. I would suggest starting from something like this, and checking it doesn't hang. Then build any additional logic from there.

```
private static string ExecuteCommand(string command, string arguments)
{
    command = System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(command);
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = arguments
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It's often hard to isolate the problem when there's so much 'dead wood' in the code. Strip it back to the bare bones, and see if you can isolate the problem from there.

Comment: I plugged this into my code and it works great up until there is a large workload on git. I noticed this issue with my old implementation as well. It appears that git is attempting to use several threads to compensate for the workload and, I assume, this is causing it to have issues. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZacharySheppard: If you're using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and sending several requests to git an once, maybe you're causing it to be overloaded. Do you need to do this?

Comment: I have guard clauses specifically geared towards not allowing commands to be executed while it's processing. That works. I don't NEED to use the threadpool, however, I wanted to provide my designers with visual feedback inside Unity while the commands execute and I can't do that while the main thread is blocked up.

Comment: You need to read the output stream when you redirect it - if you don't, the process will hang as soon as its output buffer gets full. Since you're using `WaitForExit` before doing the `ReadToEnd`, you've just managed to deadlock yourself if the process writes more than its buffer can handle to output. Just get rid of the `WaitForExit`, and keep the `ReadToEnd`.

Comment: Oh, and looking at this again - you're redirecting both Output and Error, but you're only reading Output. Again, this causes a hang if the error buffer gets full. The only way around this is to either not redirect the error stream, or to use the asynchronous read methods (e.g. `process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync()`).